# Pm2, Nginx or Nodejs doesent provide the newest Version of a deployed Route

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, fs, pm2

today I've stumbled across a big issue for one of our internal software solutions, and I have never been desperate enough to open a ticket here before, but even after consulting with another co-worker we couldn't manage to figure out what is wrong.

I guess this will turn out as a good lesson on Nginx, pm2 or Nodejs caches which might be interesting for anyone who's developing with these Applications/Frameworks.

### The Facts:

*Setup*

- Ubuntu 16.04 Server
- deployment to Server via pm2 from a Windows 10 Computer
- the application is written in nodejs v8.9.4

*Story before the Actual Error*

- The application worked for about one and a half Months after the first deployment without any problem
- Today the Application displayed the Error: [TypeError: Path must be a String. Received undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffuOh.png)
- To get the current state of the program onto the Machine, I proceeded with updating the application with pm2(s) Update functionality.
- The application worked again after the update. While deploying npm install is being executed again, and I thought it just fixed the issue.

*The actual Error*

- Through further testing, I found out that one of the download Functions for a Zip File isn't working anymore.
- After trying/testing (with mocha) the same route on my local Computer, I came to the resolution that something is wrong with the path to the location where the file shall be saved and retrieved from.
- Testing around to get further logging from the application didn't work.
- When entering the route's webpage the Nginx, pm2 or application seems to provide the old Page before I edited it. Even though the code on the Server is definitely the same as the one on my computer.
- Cognito doesn't show/uses the new page either.
- I got really assured of this fact after deploying multiple times with different other path names for the zip file to be saved in as you can see in the example. He is always trying to find a file with this path: '/web/l18n/archive.zip'
- Even though I provide a different path in the Route file the zip file is always being saved in '/web/archive.zip'

*The Code*

Don't forget that I've already played around a lot with the code to cut out some obvious issues. Both parts of the if request setting the path to where the archive.zip path should be saved are not taking any effect on the [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU0sK.png)

```js
var zip = new JSZip()

 const dictionaryName = process.env.dictionaryNames
 const splitDictionaryName = dictionaryName.split(';')

 for (const dictionary of splitDictionaryName) {
  const tempDictionaryPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../../' + process.env.dictionaryFolder + '/dictionary.' + dictionary + '.json')
  const dictionaryContent = fs.readFileSync(tempDictionaryPath, 'utf8')
  zip.file('dictionary.' + dictionary + '.json', dictionaryContent)
 }
 await zip.generateAsync({
  type: 'nodebuffer'
 })
  .then(async function (content) {
   const stateString = process.env.state | 'local'
   let archivePath = ''

   if (stateString === 'staging') {
    archivePath = '/web/l18n/current/afasfsagf.zip'
   } else {
    archivePath = path.join(__dirname, '/../aasdasfgasfgs.zip')
   }

   await fs.writeFile(archivePath, content, function (err) {
    if (err) {
     global.log.info(err)
     res.send({})
    } else {
     res.download(archivePath)
    }
   })
  }).catch(function (err) {
   global.log.err(err)
  })
```

**Routing**

The route is being directly loaded via the file provided above. Every other route, even the more advanced file handling ones are working fine.

```js
const downloadAll = require('./routes/downloadAll.js')

this.http = express() 

this.http.get('/download_all', downloadAll)
```

**Handlebars "Request"**

Being accessed is the route via a new window, being opened when a button is pressed on the main home route.

```js
$('button').click(function (event) {
  let buttonId = $(this).attr('id')
  if (buttonId === 'downloadAllDictionaries') {
   var win = window.open('/download_all')
   window.location.reload()
  }
 })
```

**Nginx**

```
server {
listen 80;


server_name ****;
access_log /var/log/nginx/****.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/****.error.log;
# pass the request to the node.js server with the correct headers
# and much more can be added, see nginx config options


location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7000;
    proxy_set_header Host **********;
    proxy_redirect off;
}

listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot

include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


if ($scheme != "https") {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
} # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Start by eliminating the unneeded parts. pm2 has nothing to do with caching if you are not use the `pm2 serve`. The nginx is used only for proxy to the express app? Can you add the route code from express? did you test the express app without nginx?

Comment: Pm2 is install as a daemonizing Service I guess that is what you mean? The nginx does only proxy to the express app, yes. I tested it locally, which is without niginx and it worked fine there. The routing is fine, for local installation too but I will add it for a better understanding :)

Comment: Just add the nginx config

Comment: BTW what do you mean by "pm2(s) Update functionality"? You need `pm2 restart <appname>` after any server side code change or using the watch option of pm2

Comment: I'm deploying the code via pm2's remote ssh deployment from my own computer. (pm2 deploy staging update) If you want to have a look at the documentation you can find it here: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/easy-deploy-with-ssh/ And yes I also checked manually if the code on the machine really was updated and started/stopped the service inside the pm2 daemon several times.

Comment: OK great, so it's called `deploy` not `update`. Please add the nginx config.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was missguided by our package.json names for the process. Nginx config is added :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure nginx isn't cache the proxied requests.

Add this 2 lines to the proxy location:

`location / {
add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate, max-age=0';
expires off;
}`

Comment: I added it to the 'location /' segment as you said. But it doesen't seem to take effect after an nginx restart. Since the route is availabel through 'domain.name/download_all' do i need to create a seperated location to add the header onto it?

Comment: No, just make sure you are getting this headers. Check the response in chrome devTools, network tab. Or simply `curl -i https://...`

Comment: The Cache-Control Header is visible on the other routes, they are returning with a 200 obviously. But the download_all route is returning with a 404 error code and in the response header is no Cache-Control. Maybe I'm missing/doing something wrong with the expires off? It doesen't show up on the successfull routes or on the 404 one. I've tried clearing the cache of my browers + ikognito mode but he doesen't seem to try to get the newest version. The path that is currently display as an error on the screen isn't even in the program anymore because I changed the name of the archive.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem.
My nodeJS app modifications are not activated.
Many thought it is the cache of Nginx or of the Browser but in fact it is PM2 that load all the JS files in memory and provide a nice acceleration feature but does not update when there is a file change for the standard installation of PM2.

Here is the solution : https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/watch-and-restart/

So in place of launching your App with

> > pm2 start MyApp.js

do

> > pm2 start MyApp.js --watch

And for the development phase, you are safe from this mysterious caching phenomenon.